# Epiphany browser with iCloud web client

Tags: epiphany

When running with the Juno release Live CD, I can login to my icloud account (www.icloud.com) with Epiphany and bring up the various services with the hashtag reference (#mail, etc.) **but** I cannot open mail messages, calendar entries, etc.  Epiphany simply does not respond and there do not appear to be any settings/preferences to help fix this problem.  Is this behavior expected?

Comment: First thing to try would be to disable the adblocker. Sadly the version of Epiphany in elementary is really not fit for use; the adblocker is blocking loads of legitimate resources, so many websites are just broken. This was fixed over a year ago but elementary isn't updating the browser.

If that doesn't work, you'll want to report a bug on WebKit Bugzilla, WebKitGTK component.